# Using layouts from others classes in vaadin

Tags: class, function, layout, parameter-passing, vaadin

Is there any idea wich allows me using layouts declared in MyApplication.java from other classes and functions.
I tried put them in parameters it works but it becomes very complicated
For example xhen callin a function named Y in function X I have to pass all layouts on parameters like this:

X(layout1,layout2,layout3,layout4)
{
Y(a,b,c,layout1,layout2,layout3,layout4)
}

I tried to use a class named uiHelper but it didn't works

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can take a look at Blackboard addon for vaadin.

> https://vaadin.com/addon/blackboard

From that page:

> Sometimes, having a deep component hierarchy poses a problem, when you need to inform a component high up in the tree that something happened deep down below. You normally have one of two choices - either pass the listener all the way down the hierarchy, leading to more coupled code, or let each component in between be a listener/notifier, passing the event all the way back up. With the Blackboard, you can register any listener to listen for any event, and when that event is fired, all the listeners for that event are triggered. This keeps your components clean and rid of unnecessary boilerplate code.

For your example, you can create a **LayoutChangeListener** and **LayoutChangeEvent**.
**MyApplication** can then implements **LayoutChangeListener** and when a **LayoutChangeEvent** is fired, you can change your layout without passing it around.

Comment: is there any example of code plezase because I created all this stuff and didn't find what to put on them

Comment: you can find detailed explanation and example here: https://github.com/wolfie/Blackboard/wiki/